# how to save documents to multiple buckets in reactive couchbase world

Tags: spring-data, reactive-programming, couchbase, reactive, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to load multiple buckets which is working fine using below code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories("com.abc.couchbase.repositories")
class ReactiveCouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

@Autowired
private CouchbaseProperties couchbaseProperties;

@Override
public String getConnectionString() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getConnectionString();
}

@Override
public String getUserName() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getUserName();
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getBucketName() {
    return couchbaseProperties.getBucketName();
}

@Bean
protected ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping configureRepositoryOperationsMapping(ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping mapping) {
    // only model that is mapped to custom template will be mapped to non-default bucket
    return mapping.mapEntity(Layout.class, layoutTemplate());
}

@Bean
public ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate layoutTemplate() {
    return customCouchbaseTemplate(customCouchbaseClientFactory("bucket2"));
}

public ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate customCouchbaseTemplate(CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory) {
    return new ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClientFactory, new MappingCouchbaseConverter());
}

public CouchbaseClientFactory customCouchbaseClientFactory(String bucketName) {
    return new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(getConnectionString(), authenticator(), bucketName);
}

@Bean
public ReactiveCluster loadReactiveCluster() {
    ClusterOptions clusterOptions = ClusterOptions.clusterOptions(couchbaseProperties.getUserName(), couchbaseProperties.getPassword());
    return ReactiveCluster.connect(couchbaseProperties.getConnectionString(), clusterOptions);
}
```

But when in my controller if i use the repository with Layout entity along with other bucket entity which is defalut bucket, i see default bucket only getting the data. Other bucket layout as configured above never gets the data .

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Layout, String> layoutRepository;
@PostMapping("/service")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<PageType> saveService(@RequestBody PageType pageType) {
    Layout layout = new Layout();
    layout.setLayoutId("dummy_101");
    layout.setPageId("dummy_11");
    repository.save(pageType).subscribe();
    layoutRepository.save(layout).subscribe();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Please help.I am using spring data couchbase 4.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/878

> @Bean
> protected ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping configureRepositoryOperationsMapping(ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping mapping)

Careful with the method names and signatures and annotations. Use @Override to ensure you are overriding the intended method.  The method you should be overriding is

> public ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping reactiveCouchbaseRepositoryOperationsMapping(
> ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate reactiveCouchbaseTemplate) {